# Why waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished doesn't wait in this code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
-(NSInteger) buttonIndexWithMessage:(NSString *) title andArrayOfOptions:(NSArray *) options
{
    self.operation=[NSOperationQueue new];

    [self.operation addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

            for (NSString * strOption in options) {
                [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:strOption];
            }

            [actionSheet showInView:[BGMDApplicationsPointers window]];
        }];
        self.operation.suspended=true; //Okay make t
    }];

    [self.operation waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];//Don't get out of the function till user act.

    //Wait till delegate is called.
    return self.buttonIndex;//I want to return buttonIndex here.
}
```

The execution point keeps moving till return self.buttonIndex even though self.operation has not finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that self.operation has not finished? The operation you add to it is very fast to execute: it just adds another operation to the main queue.

You seem to think that the line

```
self.operation.suspended=true;
```

should block the ongoing operation. But from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method suspends or resumes the execution of operations.
>   Suspending a queue prevents that queue from starting additional
>   operations. In other words, operations that are in the queue (or added
>   to the queue later) and are not yet executing are prevented from
>   starting until the queue is resumed. Suspending a queue does not stop
>   operations that are already running.

Your operation is already running, so is not affected.

Why don't you tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, and we can suggest good ways how to achieve that.

Comment: I want to turn delegate style invocation with function style. So I want to create a function that will display UIActionSheet and return the index user picks.

Comment: What you are looking for is thread synchronization. Your background thread needs to block until the button press is detected on the main thread. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html.

Comment: However, you do realize that the whole UI is asynchronous. If you really insist on using synchronous "function style" UI interaction, then you need to run your whole program in a background thread, which will lead to a large amount of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you suspend every added operation here:

```
self.operation.suspended=true;
```

So they aren't executed.

Another problem is that is not guaranteed that the block will be executed immediately, since you're just adding it to the main operation queue. Once you add it to the main operation queue you don't know when it will be scheduled. I'd change the code this way:

```
[self.operation addOperationWithBlock:^{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    for (NSString * strOption in options) {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:strOption];
    }
    [actionSheet showInView:[BGMDApplicationsPointers window]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation *has* finished! You're waiting on an operation that finishes quickly: all that operation does is add an operation to the mainQueue. The thing that happens in the mainQueue may take time the complete, but that's not the operation you're waiting on.